# How do i call my CRUD method as a list in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dao

This is my code in the class file ,  how do i call this in my xaml.cs ( code behind ) ?

```
  //Get all records based on ActivityID and TaskID and Group By ActivityID , TaskID , QuestionNo.
    public IList<QuestionHint> GetRecords1(int listTask, int listActivity)
    {
        IList<QuestionHint> lstRecords = context.questionhints.GroupBy(x => new { x.QuestionNo, x.ActivityID, x.TaskID }).ToList().Select(g => new QuestionHint()
        {
            QuestionNo = g.Key.QuestionNo,
            ActivityID = g.Key.ActivityID,
            TaskID = g.Key.TaskID
        }).Where(q => q.TaskID == listTask && q.ActivityID == listActivity)
            //.Take(50)
          .ToList();

        return lstRecords;
    } 

 public class QuestionHint
        {
            public int? QuestionNo { get; set; } //change the type accordingly 
            public int? ActivityID { get; set; } //change the type accordingly 
            public int? TaskID { get; set; } //change the type accordingly 
            public string Answer { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 
            public string QuestionContent { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 
            public string joined { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 
            public string joinOption { get; set; }   //change the type accordingly 

        }
```

And this is how i tried to use this method in my xaml.cs code behind in WPF :

```
IList<QuestionHint> lstQuestionHints = qh.GetRecords(taskID, activityID);
```

But the error says QuestionHint could not be found but i have already declare it on top like this :

```
private DAO.DAOQuestionHint qh = new DAO.DAOQuestionHint();
```

i am using entity framework with lambda expression , DAOQuestionHint is the name of the class file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler wants you either to put appropriate `using` directive for `QuestionHint` type (not for `DAO.DAOQuestionHint`, which is really declared), or use it full name like `SomeNamespace.QuestionHint.`

The easiest way to add `using` is to right-click on `QuestionHint` and to select "Resolve" from context menu.